# Difference between import .package and import package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with Python and I found two variations in Python package import statement.

What's the difference between `import .package_name` and `import package_name`?

Sample code

```
import boto3
import io
from .configurationfile import *
```

Comment: When you do `import .module`(relative import), it is saying, `import` the module from the path where the `module.py` exists. This can be done only inside a `package`, while `import module` can be done without having a package

Comment: so the file which uses .module should be inside the module folder itself?

Comment: Inside the `package`. If the import is like `import .module`, the the file that uses must be in the same level